# How to know when an upload is done?

Tags: guzzle

I'm using Guzzle 4 (latest version) to upload file to a remote server, since it uses stream to upload the $response->getStatusCode() will be 100 which means "Continue" and the responseBody is not available at this point.

Is there a way to catch the remote server response when the upload is done?

---

Edit 1:

I was able to call back to a function when the upload is done using this:
https://github.com/guzzle/progress-subscriber

However, I haven't found out how to get the response yet